# How to select distinct points in an attribute table with multiple duplicates in arcgis pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, sql, select-by-attribute

I have an attribute table with 400+ values of chemical sampling results associated with ~100 different testing sites. Each sampling site has 2-10 result values associated with it. The points are symbolized by chemical result, and I want to label each point's location. However, if I turned on the labels, it would give me multiple labels for each point.

How can I make a selection of the distinct sample locations using ArcGIS Pro?

In SQL I know it is something like
SELECT DISTINCT column name
FROM table name

I have tried writing the above SQL code in the select by attributes sql box, but this didn't work. I am new to integrating SQL into GIS workflows.

Comment: You need to show your code and a couple screen shots of your data would be helpful.

Comment: Do the records (features) have an attribute (eg, a site ID) that is unique to each site, and which is the same for all records (features) of a single site? If so, you could run a 'Dissolve' on the data, dissolving based on the site ID attribute (and preserving which ever of the other attributes you still need, merging values as required).

Comment: Usually, for this sort of thing, I would have one feature class just for the sites themselves (one record per site), and then a seperate feature class (or just a table) for the actual results (multiple records per site).  You can then join them, if necessary.

Comment: If you have unique site ideas, duplicate labels can be suppressed with Maplex rules.